# USB Keyboard and Mouse Stop Working Sometimes

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard, mouse

Recently my USB keyboard and mouse has been stopping working randomly every once in a while, and only working again after I restart my laptop. Putting them in different usb slots doesn't help, and other devices like mp3 players still work in the same usb slot. Tried using another mouse, still didn't work, but the original one worked on a different laptop. I can't see a pattern in when they stop working, and there's no recurring events.

I have windows 7, mouse is a wired optical Logitech, keyboard is a simple wired microsoft one. I have updated and uninstalled and re-installed the drivers, ran anti-virus and malware scans, and it hasn't helped. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a USB drive or other device attached? I've seen this behavior with too many USB devices that draw their power from USB are attached.

Comment: No, the only things attached are the mouse and keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

i have recently solved a similar issue.

on my windows PC the USB keyboard and USB mouse would stop working sporadically.
some LED on the keyboard started flashing. and both, keyboard and mouse would just not respond any longer!
in such situations i have always been able to remotely log into that windows machine to close any open documents, close any open programs and then trigger a reboot.
after such reboot the keyboard and mouse would be working fine again on that local windows session.
but only until the problem appeared again. a few minutes or a few hours later ...

in the end it turned out that something must have been broken inside the cable of that USB mouse.
when "moving" the mouse, that broken part in the USB cable must have occasionally caused some kind of "short circuit" or so.
eventually leading to all "USB input" no longer working.

the solution was as simple as dumping the old mouse and attaching a new USB mouse.
the problem has never come back, since.