# Keyboard and mouse being deatached during W7 work and cannot be reatached (even in differenet port) until system reboot

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard, mouse, peripherals

I have very strange problem with my USB mouse and keyboard:

Sometimes during normal work in W7 they became deatached (there is that funky sound of deataching device in W7), without any my ingeretion. They cannot be reatached until next reboot, even if I plug them out and then plug in (even in different USB slot). The mouse deatached still emit red light from under, but on screen cursor and mouse buttons are not responding. I can attach different mouse into some other port (and it's works), as I have second mouse and tried that.

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/634731/usb-keyboard-and-mouse-stop-working-sometimes , but there is no answer there either

Comment: Did you try using a different mouse and keyboard? Right now it's hard to tell whether the problem is at your mainboard's end or tied to the input devices themselves. Also, do they both use a single USB adaptor to connect to your computer or do they both have their own?

Comment: Are there some hints in the system's event log?

Comment: @Zerobinary99 Both keboard and mouse are plugged to different USB ports and there is nothing in common with them.

Comment: @ott-- There is nothing obvious, just enormous amount of informational events and a few errors in PerfLog failing to index page file (C0000005)

Comment: You should try a different set of mouse and keyboard. Also, you should test if this happens on a dual booted OS too. If so then your mainboard could be faulty. If not then it could be a software issue.

Comment: Do you still have old PS1 mouse/keyboard to try a revival?

Comment: @Zerobinary99 Could you post your comment as answer, so I can accept it? it turn out it was faulty keyboard, I replaced it with a new one and all problems I had with both keyboard and mouse disappeared.