# My input devices (mouse/keyboard) disconnect during use

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard, mouse, wired

I am having an input device problem that's interfering with my work and it has recently started occurring more frequently making it unbearable.

I have a wired Asus Mobtuo mouse and keyboard that came with my new PC about two years ago (Windows 7 64 bit, dual pentium @ 3GHz, 8GBs RAM). The keyboard and mouse don't have any visible dents either on them or their cables.

The problem started about half a year ago. Windows notified me that my mouse/keyboard have been unplugged and they became unresponsive followed by the "ping" sound notification. After a few seconds they were back on without removing or messing with them. This happened frequently but not so much to be an actual problem.

Lately though, I never hear that sound and they both become unresponsive unless I unplug them and connect them to the front USB ports if they were at the back previously or vice versa. Every time this happens I have to move both of them. The respective USB ports from which I remove them from can't be used again until I restart my PC. Other devices such as a wireless WIFI receiver and a USB stick still work on those ports. After I have connected them to my front and back USB ports and if they stop working again I have to force restart my PC losing all of my work done. An interesting point to note is that both my mouse and my keyboard are actually receiving power from the USB even though they are not working. For example my keyboard still has the "Caps Lock" icon turned on, but I can't turn it off.

Unfortunately I don't have a mouse to try which is the first logical step to combat that situation so I am asking if you have ever experienced anything like that before. I have updated every driver on my system to both their factory defaults and to their newer version if they are available to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

This has been an ongoing issue for a long time, based on web searches I have done (such as the one that led me to your question). Unfortunately, everyone has questions and nobody has answers... or at least, not anything that fixes the problem.
It's only the mouse and keyboard that are affected. Other USB devices work just fine.
I have to assume this is some kind of software incompatibility or bad update, but nobody seems to know what. Brand of mouse/keyboard doesn't seem to matter. The only common threads as far as I can tell are 1) Windows 7 (always 64 bit, often if not always Pro), 2) it only seems to happen when you're in the middle of something intensive (for me it's games), rather than just streaming video or using Google or suchlike, and 3) turning the computer off then back on always fixes it (until it breaks again), but rebooting doesn't always fix it.

If anyone has an answer to this, PLEASE post it. There are so many people having this problem, I find it hard to believe that the issue hasn't been identified and fixed somewhere.

Things that haven't worked:
* Reinstalling the drivers
* Removing the mouse in device manager, then reinstalling it
* Changing the power settings so that the USB port doesn't turn off
* Changing to a different mouse or keyboard
* Completely reinstalling Windows
* Installing a new motherboard and CPU
* Upgrading to a more powerful PSU

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet there is something *broken* in the **cable** of the USB mouse.
For example see: https://superuser.com/a/1540568/326187